# What would happen if all engineers in the world take a day/week/month off at the same time?

Tags: science-based, technology

Suppose that all the engineers in the world took a vacation at the same time for:

1. 24 hours
2. 7 days (a week)
3. 30 days (a month)

The immediate thing that comes to my mind would be that the internet might stop working, causing a state of chaos in our technology-dependent world.

Your specific thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! You say 'engineers', yet talk about the internet not working, so can I assume that you mean 'engineers and technicians' (as it's the server 'technicians' that keep the servers running on a daily basis, while no engineers would probably just mean a general lack of progress, as opposed to things breaking)?

Comment: By engineers, you mean people with specific title earned at academies, institutes etc? People with specific *work* titles? People doing specific kinds of job, no matter the title? Or what, exactly?

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 yes, I mean both engineers and technicians

Comment: @Mołot by "engineers" I mean people professionally working as engineers or technicians as mentioned in the first comment (we don't care about their academic background or actual job title, but what they actually do).

Comment: I'd suggest you pick one of the three timeframs for your question.

Comment: @Mormacil can you refer me to these concepts? (I am new around here, don't really know how exactly the questions should be phrased)

Comment: So am I, but this is their help page on the subject. 
http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Well that depends. How often to they tweak the operation they're running? How often is maintenance required? Nuclear powerplants would shut down in about two days if left running unattended. Hoover Dam on the other hand can run for weeks.

So anything a week or longer will cause massive power outages. Which in turn should crash major server parks. So large parts of the internet go down. Amazon, Cloudfire, Google. All those hosting services will go out and taking all that rely on them with it.

So we have no power, no internet, no cellphone reception. Society in the western world would break down. That's ignoring a whole array of other engineering jobs. Hospitals would be without technicians while dealing with utter chaos.

Basically the summary of it is this, our infrastructure will break after a few days. The following chaos will cause even more damage with nobody to repair it.